# JUnit paramterized testing

Tags: junit, parameterized, url-pattern

```
@Parameters(name = "{0}")
public static Collection<File> data() {
    File folder = new File("src/test/resources/test");
    return Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(folder.listFiles()));
}
```

I want to get the names of the files to be name of the test cases. can anybody help me with the pattern {name = "{0}"}

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this:

```
public TestClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "File name: {0}")
public static List<String> data() {
    File folder = new File("src/test/resources/");
    return Arrays.asList(folder.list());
}
```